# SSRS 2008 Chart - Is it possible to increase the horizontal axis label display size?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

First, here is an example of what I want to correct:

#### Problem

[image: Problem]

That screenshot is taken with the "Enable auto-fit" option marked (default of all checked).

What I have tried:

1. Various custom angles
2. [This](http://www.douglane.net/fit-chart-labels-in-ssrs/)
3. Unchecking "Labels can be offset" and "Labels can be wrapped" to see what changes, but the results are the exact same.

I was hoping 2 could solve my problem, but all I am left with is a large chunk of white space under the labels. Any suggestions?

Edit: Changed the title to better reflect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this will help, but the setting is your textbox property sizing (allow height to increase set?

Comment: Whoops I may have been unclear. The actual object is the Horizontal Axis. Within the Horizonal Axis Properties I do not see any options to increase the height.

Comment: Check this out...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/27/charts-with-dynamic-size-based-on-categories-or-data.aspx

Comment: While in the process of looking up what logic I would use for the dynamic height property I came across **[this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/769305/ssrs-chart-dynamicheight-dynamicwidth-and-whitespace-management)**. I am not sure it will help, but I am going to keep looking at that option and comment with the results.

Comment: No luck with this... made the font size 6 to fit it all in and hope they can read it.